# Resolve index duplicates (in Pandas) by combining duplicated rows

Tags: python, pandas

I combine two dataframes into a single one. This single one has duplicated index values and I would like to combine those rows with duplicated index values.
Here two rows are shown and would like to merge them by simply copying not nan values into the row with nans...
[image]

It must be easy but I am struggling to get it ...

any help is very welcomed...

Tried loads of combinations of pandas merge, concat, join etc...

Comment: `df.groupby('index').first()`